# Simple jQuery countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I have a very simple problem, but the official documentation and online help wasn't enough to help me with this.

I have this template countdown that counts days remaining until the new year.

I just want to change it so it counts to October 1st of 2016.

```
var PageComingSoon = function () {
    return {
      //Coming Soon
      initPageComingSoon: function () {
            var newYear = new Date();   
            newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear})
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: `.countdown()` is clearly a method to a library you are using. Make sure to give a link to it in your question.

Comment: All the research Ive done indicates is this one http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/
sorry

Comment: How about: `$('#defaultCountdown').countdown('2016-10-01')`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three parameters of are [`Date(year, month, day, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The given code `newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1)` clearly states that the year is next year, then the first month, and the first day (*note months start at `0`*). You likely can simply change the values of these to represent October the 1st of 2016.

```
var myDate = new Date(2016, 9, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass a date to the countdown

```js
var date = '2016/10/01';

$("#defaultCountdown")
    .countdown(date, function(event) {
        $(this).text(
            event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.1.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

`strftime()` gives you a way to format your output